# resource string/permdesc_flashlight not found

Tags: android, syntax-error, runtime-error

So I'm trying to build a flashlight app for Android (in Android Studio), but I'm getting strange errors for the permissions that say resource string/permdesc_flashlight can't be found. The same thing goes for string/permlab_flashlight.

Any ideas on why this error might occur? I have minimum sdk set to 20.

[image: Picture of error here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing string resources like:

```
<string name="permlab_flashlight">Flashlight permission</string>
<string name="permdesc_flashlight">Flashlight permission description</string>
```

These should be in your `strings.xml`

Comment: Cool! It worked! I've got another thing to iron out, but it's unrelated to this question and it's on my end. Thanks!